# start Id from 10 not 1 in mvc Code Firstوstart auto increment from a specific point

Tags: model-view-controller, code-first

this is my model in code first and i use Id as Key in normal for index and identity of my table

```
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public int MainGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual MainGroup  mainGroup { get; set; }
```

my problem is: how to start auto increment from a specific point in code first, 
when I add an item to database, in default mode *id* start from 1 but I want start from 10, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use an identity column, and customize your database initialization or migration to set the seed of your identity column.

The `T-SQL` command to do this is:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Offer', RESEED, 123);
```

Note that the next inserted value is not 123, but 123 + increment (124 if default increment of 1).

You can also use a column with the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` and a sequence as default value for your field (if you're using a recent SQL server version). When you create a sequence, you can specify the initial value and increment:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE OfferNoSeq
START WITH 1 -- Initial Value
INCREMENT BY 1 -- Increment
```

An attach this sequence as a default for the OfferNo column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Offer ADD CONSTRAINT OfferNoSeq 
DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR OfferNoSeq)  FOR OfferNo;
```

There is no direct way to implement this in Code First. So, for using any of these options, you need to

- [[Customize DB Initialization]](http://omerc.blogspot.in/2012/04/entity-framework-code-first-data.html) This is done by implementing your own
  database initializer class and execute the desired SQL commands from
  the Seed methods (look for the implementation of public class
  MyInitializer in the linked article)
     or to [Customize migration](http://omerc.blogspot.in/2012/04/entity-framework-code-first-data.html): you can execute any SQL Command in the Up() or Down() method of your migration, as shown in the
  linked answer